# Index out of range exception while deleting row from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting error like

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection"

when trying to delete row of gridview. My aspx.cs code is below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        main delete=new main();

        // int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].Value);
        // string ID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ToString();
        sQLcONN.Open();
        string Query = "delete  * from shoppingcart where shoppingcart.with_puja = '"+Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString())+"' ";
        delete.deleteData(Query);
        Bindgrid();
        sQLcONN.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: check for value of e.RowIndex,it must be wrong

Comment: You really need to sort your code formatting and naming out first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `DataKeys` part is the culprit, it must be something like this:

```
string Query = "delete from shoppingcart where shoppingcart.with_puja = '" + Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.DataKeys["nameOfKey"].Value).ToString() + "'";
```

or something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        main delete = new main();
        DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTatable;

        sQLcONN.Open();
        string Query = "delete from shoppingcart where shoppingcart.with_puja = '" + Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["nameOfKey"]).ToString() + "'";
        delete.deleteData(Query);
        Bindgrid();
        sQLcONN.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }
}
```

Where `nameOfKey` is the column name of the table which is `with_puja` in your case and `GridView1` must be `e.Item` if `e` has an `Item` property.

Comment: I got an error as Gridview doesnot contain a defination of Item.

Comment: Like what I said, replace `GridView1` with `e.Item`

Comment: ah try extracting it from the `DataSource` of the grid like what I included in my updated answer

Comment: I am getting error column (with_puja) doesnot exit in the table but I have in my table.Which column should be give inside[""]?

Comment: Thankyou nathan for your answers but I think now my deletedata functions is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataKeys` in `GridView` would be like:

```
 DataKeyNames="Id, foo, foo"
```

and then try to use string like this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex][0].ToString()); // 0 is the index and in this case Id will be at zero
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this question annoyed the Bejebus out of me, but couldn't figure it out until today.

My Situation:

- A database novice.
- Set up my own database.
- Using ASP.NET with MySQL, phpMyAdmin
- For some reason, only one of my table's had this issue.

---

In searching for a solution, I decided to open up my database and change the offending table's storage engine from **MyISAM to InnoDB**.

And that alone fixed the issue.

**But that's only a clue** as to the real problem. In my case, the offending table was far more read-heavy, changing only occasionally, so MyISAM is what I wanted it to be.

**The key difference** here is that MyISAM is stricter with input. As you can see above, there's a lot of Int32 converting going on. So, try this:

- Open up your database, table
- Check your table's id field
- Is its type some form of "Int"
- Is the Value/Length field anything other than 32?

Hope that saves someone else some time and grief.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the row index as CommandArgument.

In the event method on server:

```
int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
string val = (string)this.grid.DataKeys[rowIndex]["myKey"];
```

On the button use:

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'
```

**EDIT:**

Query:

```
string Query = "delete  * from shoppingcart where shoppingcart.with_puja = '"+val +"' ";
```

I recommend to use parameters to avoid [sql injections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: how will be the query den?

Comment: you just replace what you have there with val, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string Query = "delete * from shoppingcart where shoppingcart.with_puja = '" + Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Id"].ToString()) + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

sum += Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining how exactly this would help.