# Index out of range for delete in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sharepoint

The following is the code to delete a row from Grid View and update the Content list thereby. But it gives Index out of range exception.

The designer code of Grid view is here.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewD" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="RoyalBlue" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCancelingEdit="Cancel_Edit" OnRowDeleting="GridViewD_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="Edit_Row" OnRowUpdating="Update_Row">
     <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cellphone" HeaderText="Contact" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />      
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lbldata" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Here is the code behind.

```
protected void GridViewD_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    try
    {

        GridViewRow row = GridViewD.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string itemId;
        itemId = ((TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
        // itemId = GridViewD.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        DeleteRow(itemId);
        Bind_Data();
    }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}

private void DeleteRow(string itemId)
{


    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Advertisement");
            SPListItem item = null;
            item = list.GetItemById(int.Parse(itemId));
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            item.Delete();
            list.Update();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }




}
```

> Index out of range exception.

How to resolve it ?

Comment: At which line it errors out?

Comment: While initializing itemid. It is giving error that index is out of range

Comment: @ShahrozShaikh, put your gridview design code.

Comment: This is solved here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847161/index-out-of-range-exception-while-deleting-row-from-gridview

Comment: But i am not updating it in database. i have to delete it from a list in sharepoint web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `itemId` is getting `null` number. Please put breakpoint and check the `itemId` is getting correct value or not.

You can try to change your template into item template and use the following method to get the value.

```
GridViewRow row = GridViewD.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Label itemIdLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("YourLabelNameitemtemp");
string itemId = itemIdLabel.Text;
```

Hope this help.